# Flexbox 100% height Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have found the following links... but it still doesn't help me...

[how to make nested flexboxes work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639129/how-to-make-nested-flexboxes-work)
[Height 100% on flexbox column child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959600/height-100-on-flexbox-column-child)
[How to make flexbox children 100% height of their parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381172/how-to-make-flexbox-children-100-height-of-their-parent)

I need a full page that is responsive, like the following image:
[image: full page]
With header and footer and the middle 5 columns filling the height equally in the remaining space, and then when I do media queries, fill the screen of the mobile device like so:

[image: mobile view]

Here's the code I have so far...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.yellow-back {
    background: #ffe001;
}

.red-back {
    background: #e31e25;
}

.green-back {
    background: #66af45;
}

.purple-back {
    background: #954294;
}

.containerFull                                  { position: relative; width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;}
.containerFull .column,
.containerFull .columns                         { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; }
.containerFull .one-fifth.column                { width: 20%; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">

  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>

    <div class="row content">

        <div class="containerFull">    
            <div class="one-fifth column green-back">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column red-back">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column yellow-back">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column purple-back">Here</div>
        </div><!-- ContainerFull -->

    </div>

  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
      flex-grow: 0,
      flex-shrink: 1,
      flex-basis: auto
      */
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.yellow-back {
  background: #ffe001;
}

.red-back {
  background: #e31e25;
}

.green-back {
  background: #66af45;
}

.purple-back {
  background: #954294;
}

.containerFull {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.containerFull .column,
.containerFull .columns {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.containerFull .one-fifth.column {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="row content">

    <div class="containerFull">
      <div class="one-fifth column green-back">Here</div>
      <div class="one-fifth column red-back">Here</div>
      <div class="one-fifth column">Here</div>
      <div class="one-fifth column yellow-back">Here</div>
      <div class="one-fifth column purple-back">Here</div>
    </div>
    <!-- ContainerFull -->

  </div>

  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add that I want the background image or color to fill the space... Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this post could help you. [Content within div won't fill available space without specifying height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922077/content-within-div-wont-fill-available-space-without-specifying-height/43922584#43922584), Check that you are setting your body´s height to 100vh, then setting the rest of your contents height will be easier. Also use a CSS reset file, to avoid weird behaviours.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to Michael Coker's answer, if you go all the way with Flexbox, you can cut down both your markup and CSS quite much and get this amazing result.

I also included the background image and media query you commented/asked about just to show how simple this can be done.

*Made some notes in the CSS. When it comes to the header and footer, you can give them a height if you want, but is not needed for this to work, so I left them out so one can see how Flexbox excel in distributing the content...wish I had this technique 20 years ago :)*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;          /* instead of using 100% all over, use viewport units once */
  background-size: cover;
  background: black url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nature/4/) no-repeat center;
}
.box .row.content,
.content .one-fifth.column {
  flex: 1;                /* fill the space equal, no matter row or column direction */
  display: flex;
}

.box .row.header,
.box .row.footer { color: white; }
.box .row.content { background: #fff; }
.yellow-back { background: #ffe001; }
.red-back { background: #e31e25; }
.green-back { background: #66af45; }
.purple-back { background: #954294; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  /* smaller screens */
  .box .row.content {
    flex-direction: column;   /* by simply swap direction it work on smaller screen */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b><br /><br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>

  <div class="row content">
    <div class="one-fifth column green-back">Here</div>
    <div class="one-fifth column red-back">Here</div>
    <div class="one-fifth column">Here</div>
    <div class="one-fifth column yellow-back">Here</div>
    <div class="one-fifth column purple-back">Here</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @lgson This is awesome and works like a charm! Now... all I need is the icon (PNG) and the heading below, to stay in the middle of the flex height box, and then when on a mobile device, the icon must shift to the left and the heading to the right of the icon. Do-able?

Comment: @LGSon Perfect! I'm not gay, but I think I might have to marry you! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would make the column section a flex layout, too. You can set `.content` and `.containerFull` to `display: flex`, then `.containerFull` will "stretch" to fill the height of `.content`, and then you can use `flex-basis` on the columns to control the width.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.box .row {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

.box .row.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /* The above is shorthand for:
  flex-grow: 0,
  flex-shrink: 1,
  flex-basis: auto
  */
}

.box .row.content {
  display: flex;
}

.box .row.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.containerFull {
  display: flex;
}

.box .row.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
}

.yellow-back {
  background: #ffe001;
}

.red-back {
  background: #e31e25;
}

.green-back {
  background: #66af45;
}

.purple-back {
  background: #954294;
}

.containerFull {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.containerFull .column,
.containerFull .columns {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.containerFull .one-fifth.column {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="row header">
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>

    <div class="row content">

        <div class="containerFull">    
            <div class="one-fifth column green-back">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column red-back">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column yellow-back">Here</div>
            <div class="one-fifth column purple-back">Here</div>
        </div><!-- ContainerFull -->

    </div>

  <div class="row footer">
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted yours, I just had to post an answer of my own, as this is a classic question where flexbox do really good with extremely little code and markup :)